# How to load more data on scroll with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How would I load more data on scroll event inside an ng-repeat?
I have feed.id which is the auto increment id in the table of media. While having say var dataCount = '5' (Being the amount of data on one scroll, then when you scrol past the 5 pieces of data it loads 5 more?

Here is the controller:

```js
.controller('feedCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory) {

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.session_id = sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});
    }
    else {
        var fload = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php';

        $http.post(fload, {id : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });

        var floadp = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load_post.php';

        $http.post(floadp, {id : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.feedload = res.data;
        });
        $scope.fposttxt = {};
        $scope.submit = function() {
            
            var fpost = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_post.php';

            $http.post(fpost, {textpost : $scope.fposttxt.text, uid : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
                var floadp = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php';
                $http.post(floadp, {id : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
                    $scope.response = res.data;
                });
            });  
        }
    }

})
```

Here is the html:

```html
<div ng-repeat="feed in response">

    <ion-list id="search-list5">
      <ion-item class="item-avatar" id="search-list-item12">
        <img ng-src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.profile_image}}">
        <h2>{{feed.format}} {{feed.firstname}} {{feed.lastname}}</h2>
        <p>Posted at {{feed.time}} on {{feed.date}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <style>
    #{{feed.media_post_id}} {
      background:url("https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.media_file_format}}/{{feed.media_post_id}}{{feed.media_author_id}}.{{feed.media_file_format}}");
    }
    </style>
    <div ng-if="feed.media_format === 'img'" style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239); text-align: center;">
      <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" id="{{feed.media_post_id}}" type="image" ion-utils-cache-base6 ng-src="{{feed.image_main}}" />
      
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body" id="search-list-item-container3">
      <div id="search-markdown6" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
        <p style="margin-top:0px;color:#000000;">{{feed.mediatxt}}
        </p>
        <p>
              <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
              <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: maybe try ngInfiniteScroll:
https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html

Comment: Exactly it is ngInfiniteScroll

Comment: Just found that out.. Oops. Although how would I go about implementing it? I'm quite new to angularjs

Comment: help would be greatly appreciated...